# What is the location of "Android Target" for Android Studio?

Tags: cordova, android-studio

While trying to setup PhoneGap for Android Studio, I ran the create script:

`./create /home/sander/development-tools/AndroidStudioProjects/DashClock com.sandernem.dashclock DashClock`

and ended up with this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN=”${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}” exited with 1
```

So I followed [this](http://www.geekgonenomad.com/code/phonegap-android-errors/) guide to set the ANDROID_BIN variable within the create script.
Problem is, when I try to set it myself approximately I end up with the following error:

```
No Android Targets are installed. Please install at least one via the android SDK
```

What is the exact path I should set the ANDROID_BIN to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio includes an SDK with platform API 17 (at least it does on windows). This sdk is located in the same location where android studio is installed, inside a subfolder called **sdk**. If you want to use this set the ANDROID_BIN value to the **/tools** subfolder in the sdk subfolder of your android studion installation.

However, I find it easier to keep my own SDK install in a separate location, so you can just install you own version by grabbing the installer [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (you should download one of the packages under the **DOWNLOAD FOR OTHER PLATFORMS** heading. Once you have that installed, run the SDK and download what you need - just make sure you download everything under **Tools** as well as at least one SDK Platform (depending on your target version).

Once installed you need to set the ANDROID_BIN value to the **/tools** subfolder of the sdk you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you instaled any android version "sdk platform" with SDK Manager.exe that comes with android ADT ?

Using linux you can open sdk manager trough eclipse: `Window-> Android SDK Manager`,

Check also this :

- `Project-> Properties -> Android ->` Project Build Target:

there u must choose one target version, which u installed previously with SDK Manager

Comment: Since I am using Android Studio, doesn't it all come preinstalled or do I need Eclipse and Android ADT regardless?

Comment: m8, android ADT = Eclipse + plugins

Comment: this answer applies to Eclipse, not Android Studio and thus doesn't fit here.